# suftesi - adapt to slightly different papersize

Tags: suftesi

I use the `suftesi` documentclass to produce a book with multiple articles with the paper size `compactaureo` which has a page size of 160 by 240 mm. My publisher forces me to use a paper size of 156 by 234 mm, which is just a few mm off.

What is the best approach to adapt the papersize? Should I add another papersize in my copy of the suftesi.cls (and if so, what should be changed beside the paper size and the text size?) or can I just insert a geometry in the `tex` file. Alternatively, I could scale the pdf produced by factor 1.0256 at the end.

I would prefer to add a `geometry to the`tex` file, but worry about interferences. Any experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is so small that I'd go with a suitable `\geometry`, by modifying `paperwidth` and `paperheight` in the options.

```
\documentclass[pagelayout=compactaureo,version=screen]{suftesi}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\geometry{
  paperwidth=156mm,% was 160mm
  paperheight=234mm,% was 240mm
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\kant

\chapter{First}

\kant

\end{document}
```

What `geometry` does is in the log file (and on the console because of `verbose`):

```
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: custom
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* hratio: 2:3
* vratio: 2:3
* modes: twoside heightrounded 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(43.24817pt, 335.74251pt, 64.87231pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(48.93872pt, 543.44763pt, 73.40813pt)
* \paperwidth=443.86299pt
* \paperheight=665.79448pt
* \textwidth=335.74251pt
* \textheight=540.0pt
* \oddsidemargin=-29.02182pt
* \evensidemargin=-7.39767pt
* \topmargin=-53.39876pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=18.06749pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=25.29494pt
* \marginparwidth=54.06023pt
* \marginparsep=9.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidetrue
* \@mparswitchtrue
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)
```

[image]

The same without the change in `\geometry`:

[image]

Comment: thank you - it works perfectly and I hope it does not mess up other aspects of the layout. (I was on trip and could not try it earlier...)

Comment: When I now consider the layout I feel that the header is too close to the top (9mm) and the free space at the bottom is too large (29mm). Is there an easy way to shift the page a bit down or is this intended? It would be ok if includehead and includefoot were set? My output seems to show that includefoot was set (footnotes are inside the text body) but this is not the case for the header?

Comment: @user855443 Do measuring and decide for the best layout. The bigger space at the bottom seems a precise choice of `suftesi`.